# NetSuite Online HTML Form - link to list within NetSuite

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, html-select, netsuite

I have an online html form that uses a select field to choose a record from an existing record list (postcodes specifically) which then auto-populates other fields on the form with the rest of the address. This all works fine except that the dropdown list on the form only goes up so far. I need to know if this a limit on the html dropdown or how many records can be passed to the list in the first place?
Also, ideally, it would be great if there was a way to do it via auto-complete so as you start typing the postcode, it only shows those beginning with said characters - is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set up a custom html template for your online form. You can then hide your standard field and include a custom text input field. Attach an event handler to the custom field to do the lookup via a suitelet. If the auto-population is already working then your event handler can update the hidden standard field once a match is made so Netsuite's built-in sourcing works.

Comment: Hi, i'm using a custom template at the moment - can you give an example of the custom field and suitelet code to do this?

Comment: a custom field is just the appropriate html for a form field <input>, <select> etc.  see next answer for sample suitelet code

Answer (score 0):

A sample suitelet. The get... functions return anything that can be JSON used by your page.

```
function service(request, response) {
    var obj = {
        success: true
    };
    try {
        var step = request.getParameter('step') || 'start';
        switch (step) {
            case 'start':
                obj.choices = getChoiceRoots(request.getParameter('itemid'), request.getParameter('treeName'));
                break;
            case 'other':
                obj.choices = getChoiceChildren(request.getParameterValues('choiceIds[]') || request.getParameterValues('choiceIds'));
                break;
            default:
                throw "Unexpected step: " + step;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        obj.success = false;
        obj.message = e.message || e.toString();
        nlapiLogExecution('ERROR', "error getting choices", (e.message || e.toString()) + "<br> " + request.getURL() + (e.getStackTrace ? "<br> " + e.getStackTrace().join("<br> ") : ''));
    }
    _sendJS(request, response, obj);

    function _sendJS(request, response, respObject) {
        response.setContentType('JAVASCRIPT'); //'application/json');
        var callbackFcn = request.getParameter("jsoncallback") || request.getParameter('callback');
        if (callbackFcn) {
            response.writeLine(callbackFcn + "(" + JSON.stringify(respObject) + ");");
        } else response.writeLine(JSON.stringify(respObject));
    }
}
```

Then on your page you'd have a script that uses the suitelet. (the suitelet needs to be available without login and the audience needs to be All.

The code on your custom template or associated script file would look something like:

```
//suiteletURL will look like https://forms.netsuite.com. RegExp makes that root relative to the domain you are on. 
//This is not actually necessary when using JSONP but it can be useful in some circumstances so I left it in this example.

$.getJSON(suiteletURL.replace(new RegExp(".*://[^/]+/"), '/')+"&"+$.param(params) +"&callback=?",
    function(d, txtStatus,xhr){
        if(d.errorCode){
            if(fail){
                fail(xhr, txtStatus, null);
            }else{
                showMessage("#appMessage", d.errorMessage || ("Request Failed with code: "+xhr.responseJSON.errorCode));
            }
        }else{
            success(d, txtStatus, xhr); // your custom success handler. d is already an object; no parsing necessary.
        }
    });
```